# Is this phrase correct? "SNP erases dads from family life"

Tags: grammar

I recently saw the following headline on the front page of a national newspaper:

"SNP erases dads from family life"

While I have little confidence in my knowledge of grammar, and doubt a national newspaper would make such an obvious grammar mistake on their front page, the sentence doesn't sound right to me. It seems to be like it should read:

"SNP erase dads from family life"

Is the use of "erases" correct in this context?

For reference, the SNP are a political party.

Comment: It's "headline grammar".  And sounds OK to me.  SNP is a single entity, so the singular verb form "erases" is used.  (But to some degree this is a UK/US thing -- in the UK organizations are sometimes treated as plural, I gather.)

Answer (score 2):

The question of whether you prefer "SNP erases dads from family life" over "SNP erase dads from family life", or "The SNP is a political party" over "The SNP are a political party", is not one of 'correct' versus 'incorrect', but of the geographical/social milieu in which you were raised and/or whose linguistic norms you have adopted. (See, for instance, the pertinent comment made by Hot Licks.)